# Wordpress "WP Google Plus Connect" Plugin > Options page invisible

Tags: wordpress

So, I installed the [WP Google Plus Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-google-plus-connect/) plugin, v 1.0.5.1. When I go to the settings page of the plugin, however, what I see is [image: this]
The settings page is not displayed.

I use Wordpress v 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved for version 1.0.5.1.
In `admin.php` in the plugin directory, on **line 60**, remove the `-->` from the end.
Then, create a new line between **line 60** and **61** and place the `-->` there.

### Explanation

This is a simple HTML mistake. The author seems to had wanted to temporarily remove some setting pages from view. So, he starts an HTML comment on **line 58**. Then, he checks whether the function named `wds_bp_check` exists, and if so, outputs another commented out link, and closes the HTML comment.

The problem is that if the function wds_bp_check does not exist, the HTML comment is not closed, and continues throughout the rest of the page, until it hits another `-->`. Thus, the settings pages are there, but are invisible. Close the comment in the appropriate place, and everything should be fixed =)